# How to destroy a record when there is many-to-many relationship in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

In my app there is recipes and ingredients, so a recipe can have many ingredients and a ingredient can be used in many recipes, everything is ok and when I create recipes there is a table called Has_ingredient where is saved every ingredient per recipe.

The thing is, now when I try to destroy a recipe there is a error, because I need to destroy the record in Has_ingredient associated with that recipe before delete the recipe.

So in my model I created something like this

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_destroy :destroy_ingredents
    ....
    ....
    ....
    def destroy_ingredents

       HasIngredent.destroy(recipe_id: self.id)
    end
```

Well, now I get this error: OCIERROR: ORA-00904.

So now the problem is not Rails, but the database (Im using Oracle), but im pretty sure the problem is how im using destroy method but I cant figure how to use it properly to delete every record in has_ingredent table associated with certain recipe

Answer (score 4):

The best way to destroy the children would be using the `dependent`

So in your model, you would have:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As @pauloancheta suggested, is the better way to leave these with rails. However if you want to know the correct syntax,

```
HasIngredent.find_by(recipe_id: self.id).destroy
```